# Laravel Pennant Class Alias

Tags: php, laravel

Given I create a new class-based feature in Laravel Pennant with: `php artisan pennant:feature Example`

It will produce a class similar this:

```php
class ExampleFeature
{
    /**
     * Resolve the feature's initial value.
     */
    public function resolve(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which is all fine, except when I come to check if this feature is accessible I have to either use the imported class, or the fully imported class name:

```
Feature::active(ExampleFeature::class) 

--OR--

@feature(app\Features\ExampleFeature::class)
```

For clarity sake, I am not willing to define these in the AppServiceProvider as there would be far too many and these should be unit tested. Is there any way I can set some sort of an alias property to reference this more easily like is possible when defining in the AppServiceProvider:

```
Feature::define('some-alias-here', fn (User $user) => match (true) {
            ...
        });
```